# Typing a record of a known type

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```
export interface IWatchEventPayload<T> {
  value?: T;
  paths?: IMultiPathUpdates[];
  changed?: IWatchEventChanges<T>;
}
```

I want the `changed` property to be a dictionary of properties which are/have undergone change. The idea then from a *typing* perspective is to ensure that keys of the dictionary  are all property of **T**. Here's how I first attempted it:

```
export interface IWatchEventChanges<T, K extends keyof T> {
  [prop: K]: [T[K], T[K]];
}
```

This, I had hoped, would give me the hash property typed and ensure that the "before" and "after" values are also typed. Sadly this lead to an error stating in `[prop: K]` that `prop` must be a string or number. In reality it will always be a string so I did the following:

```
export interface IWatchEventChanges<T, K extends keyof T> {
  [prop: Pick<K, string>]: [T[K], T[K]];
}
```

But now the original error is retained and now I also get the following on the `string` type:

> Type 'string' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof K'.
>     Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"toString" | "valueOf"'.

Things are getting messy and I'm a bit stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13573

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this as an `interface`, but you can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) instead and give it a name via a [`type` alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases), which is more flexible.  The definition you want is probably something like:

```
export type IWatchEventChanges<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: [T[K], T[K]];
}
```

Hope that helps; good luck!